# How to handle socket exceptions to make a continuous flow of program in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket

I am creating a skribbl clone in Java using JavaFX and socket programming.

I am sending data over a TCP connection using a objectinput/outputstream.

Every 2/5 times the application runs without any exception but other time it shows numerous socket related exception and I am not able to figure out why it is happening.

```
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2854)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:3181)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3191)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1621)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:488)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:446)
    at com.nttd.wtdoodle.Client.Game.Server.PlayerHandler$1.run(PlayerHandler.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Error sending Message to clien
```

```
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1701)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2479)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2373)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1670)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:488)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:446)
    at com.nttd.wtdoodle.Client.Game.Player.PtoSBridge$1.run(PtoSBridge.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Error sending Message to client
```

There is one more exception which is the `ClassCastException`. I don't know why these exceptions are occurring sometimes but not all the time.

I want to know if the objectoutput/inputstream will be suitable for this work or not.

Can you suggest any other stream that will be useful for this purpose?

Thank You for all the replies and answer . I have changed the ObjectStream to BufferedReader and BufferedWriter and it solved my problem.

Comment: "Connection reset" means the other side got your request but denied it for some reason.  Could be out of resources, or the port busy, or the firewall blocked it.

Comment: "ClassCastException" is just plain an error on your part, you did something wrong.  We'll need to see the code in question, with a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: @markspace has given you some good information on the errors that you are encountering. To your question of "will be suitable..." the answer is "no, not really" there are better alternatives

Comment: to start with, I would highly recommend that you use webserversockets instead of regular Java sockets - they are easier to use and to get up to speed with

Comment: I would also recommend using XML or JSON instead of Java object serialization, which suffers both from being Java-only as well as from not being compatible with other programming platforms.

Comment: Within XML/JSON, you are going to want to set up a communication protocol (like http for web pages) which is powerful/flexible enough to support the kinds of messages you would like to send.

Comment: Finally, you probably want to structure your communication protocol to always or sometimes use GZIP (ala HTML has a header for letting the receiver know if the body of the communication is GZIP'ped)

Comment: For testing purpose i am running multiple clients on the same machine , can this be a cause of these error?

Comment: Yes/no.  If your firewall is somehow blocking requests, yes it could be the machine.  It also might not be.  If the code is just variable or there's a timing issue, that could also cause it.  Without code and a detailed description of the test, it could be anything.

Comment: @VinayakKushwaha It also just occurred to me that "connection reset" is also what you get when there's no server listening on a port.  So it definitely could be a timing issue, where the server isn't up and running before you launch the client.  This might be the most likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we always must have in mind whether programming network code is: later or sooner something wrong will happen: parcial data delivery, disconnection, duplicates, etc. Even using TCP (a transport layer protocol with some important guarantees), your application layer must assume that a very wide range of network problems will eventually happen.

Although you didn't show your code, we can deduce by the stacktrace that you're exchange structured data, probably large structured data in the form of encoded java objects.
The problems with this strategy are:

- if the objects are always the same shape, there are a considerable overhead of always being sending/reading this same metadata which can be avoided. The bigger the data, the prone to get network errors. Consider to encode only the required data in order to avoid continuously send the same metadata.
- If even a small part of the serialized version of your object is missed or jammed, the received cannot restore the object. It is better than the scenario where the receiver tries to restore the object with incomplete or inconsistent data. As result, java thorws exceptions to sinalize it for you. Once you get an exception, you must to code what to do: ask to the remote pier resend the data, reconnect the socket, etc.

We cannot say exactly what happens to your code without see the code. But by what I can see, the solution is to properly implement the "unhappy paths" inside the catch blocks